# Designing a Search bar and retrieving data from database rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

Now i am tried by following to this article http://www.rymcmahon.com/articles/2

My product.rb file is

```
 class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   def self.search(search) 
    where("name LIKE ?","%#{search}%")
   end
 end
```

my index file is

## Data

```
 <%= form_tag(products_path, :method => "get") do %>
   <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "products" %>
   <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
 <% end %>
```

my index method is

```
def index
  @product = Product.all
 if params[:search]
  @recipes = Product.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
 else
  @recipes =Product.all.order("created_at DESC")
 end
end
```

But it didn't filtering the data
my output is:

```
 dinesh 200 2016-09-21 06:10:40 UTC
 reddyc 300 2016-09-21 06:16:31 UTC
 Goods 200 2016-09-21 09:33:56 UTC
```

Comment: please paste the index form

Answer (score 1):

That article doesn't seem to be entirely correct, because the first collection assignment seems redundant. I'd write it like this:

```
def index
  @products = search_products.order(created_at: :desc)
end

private

def search_products
  if params[:search]
    Product.search(params[:search])
  else
    Product.all
  end
end
```

Then in your views you use `@products` variable instead of `@recipes`. It should work

Answer (score 0):

You have taken two different variables for product, also `@product = Product.all` is not required, as your taking the product variable again in both if and else cases.

```
def index
    if params[:search].present?
    @products = Product.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC") //I recommend taking plural(products)
    else        
    @products = Product.all.order("created_at DESC")
    end
end
```

Your **index.html.erb** can be,

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= product.field1 %></td>
      <td><%= product.field2 %></td>
      <td><%= product.field3 %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: Yes,but it is not filtering the search string

Comment: chnage if condition to , `if params[:search].present?`, if still not solved, please paste the server log from terminal.

Comment: Thanks, for your answer it is good but i didn't succeded.Now I am trying in different way by restful links by using link_to

Comment: are you getting the search param in index action?

Comment: I tried with your  solution my search query string is not passing through params and data is not filtering.

Comment: so you are not getting params in the controller?

Comment: once try this, `<%= text_field_tag :search, "search", params[:search] || {} `%>

Comment: I am  new to backend. I can handle static views and data.But bit harder for me while dealing with dynamic data can you help me by your suggestions.

Comment: sorry,bro I didn't getting what that method do.Really sorry if u don't mind can you share your solutions to Dinesh.pallapa0@gmail.com

Comment: replace the `text_field_tag ` with the one in this comment.

Comment: Good but how to  pass this parameter  to our index method in product controller.

Comment: add  `render :text => params and return false` as first line in index method and press submit. and tell me what is displayed in the browser.

Comment: Thanks you very much.I am unable to understand  your methods.I am failed   while I am passing my search string to index method Product.search(params[:search])

Comment: change your index method to this and submit form, and tell me what happened,

`def index

 render text: params and return false
    if params[:search].present?
    @products = Product.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC") //I recommend taking plural(products)
    else        
    @products = Product.all.order("created_at DESC")
    end
end`

Comment: seperate the lines, i am unable to post the comment line by line

Comment: sorry I am making u trouble more by my problem

Comment: np, did you try that

Comment: I tried but i didnt find search result may br problem with routes

Comment: hello,sravan thanks Finally I did it by your suggustions.

Comment: sorry,sravan I already voted to ur solution but I have reputitions less than 15 thats why its not displaying.

Answer (score 0):

My controller is:

```
def show
 @product = Product.find(params[:id])
end

def search

end

 def searchable
   searchword = params[:search]
   @data = Product.where(name: searchword)
 end
```

and my searchable.html.erb is:

```
 <h1>searching for '<%= params[:search] %>'</h1>

 <% if @data.empty? %>
   <h1>no results found</h1>
 <% end %>

 <% @data.each do |s| %>
   <%= s.name %>
   <%= s.created_at %><br>
<% end %>
```

And search.html.erb

```
   <%= form_tag searchable_path, method: 'get' do  %>
     <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>  
     <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil %>
   <% end %>
```

And my routes are assigned as

```
  get 'search' => 'products#search'
  get 'searchable' => 'products#searchable'
```

By this I am able to  search data in my database.And it is working fine.